# BeautifulSoup converting apostrophes to 'â\x80\x99'

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I can't figure out how to convert the output of my BeautifulSoup code into a regular Python string. Where there should be an apostrophe, there is this: 'â\x80\x99'. Thanks for your help.

```
â\x80\x99
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539010/apostrophes-are-printing-out-as-%C3%A2-x80-x99) it explains ISO 8859-1 and few possible causes. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but was hoping there was a simpler solution that didn’t require digging around on my computer to adjust source code or the way it interprets information. Def not my area of expertise.

Comment: I suggest you post your source code so we/others can come up with a solution. Thanks!